# Org-babel: referring to variables from different code block

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I want to check out if org-mode could be a good replacement for Jupyter notebooks.
Is there a way to export **all** variables from a code block to other code blocks?

Example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python
a = 1
b = 2
#+END_SRC
```

How could I use this in other code block? For example I'd like the following to evaluate so that c = 3

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python
c = a + b
#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved using session feature:

```
#+NAME b1
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session example :results output
a = 1
b = 2
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC python :session example :results output
c = a + b
print(c)
#+END_SRC
```

Will return

```
#+RESULTS:
: 3
```